# How to remove redundant commits after 'git reset --soft' and 'git commit'

Tags: git

Say I have a Git repo set up like this:

```
$ git init test && cd test
$ touch a && git add . && git commit -m "add a"
$ touch b && git add . && git commit -m "add b"
$ touch c && git add . && git commit -m "add c"
$
$ git --no-pager log --pretty="%h %s" # print short SHA and message subject
176d6d0 add c
495991e add b
1d8444a add a
```

Now for some reasons, I want to squash the most recent 2 commits (`176d6d0 add c` and `495991e add b`) into one [1]:

```
$ git reset --soft 1d8444a # go back to the first commit ("add a")
$ git add . && git commit -m "bc"
$
$ git --no-pager log --pretty="%h %s"
c01e64a bc
1d8444a add a
```

Yeah, it looks we are done!

**Not quite!**

If we look at `git reflog show`, the old commits are still around:

```
$ git --no-pager reflog show
c01e64a (HEAD -> master) HEAD@{0}: commit: bc
1d8444a HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to 1d8444a9747bd5e4176c
176d6d0 HEAD@{2}: commit: add c                           # old commit
495991e HEAD@{3}: commit: add b                           # old commit
1d8444a HEAD@{4}: commit (initial): add a
```

If we checkout an old commit, we can still restore it.

```
$ git --no-pager show -s 176d6d0 # this is the "add c" commit
commit 176d6d0aa92b230f4dd1e4ed8ae028b7c5fbb2d5
Author: XXX <XXX@XXX.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 22 22:19:23 2019 -0400

    add c

$ git checkout 176d6d0
Note: checking out '176d6d0'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around
... # omitted

HEAD is now at 176d6d0 add c
```

**I tried to delete these stale old commits, but none of these works**, the old commits are still visible in `git reflog show` and `git checkout`-able:

```
git gc
git gc --prune=all
git reflog expire --all
git reflog expire --expire=now
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now
git reflog expire --expire=now --all # tricky, see update below
```

**Questions**:

1. How should I *really* discard the old commits (`176d6d0 add c` and `495991e add b`)?
2. What's the jargon for these old commits (`176d6d0 add c` and `495991e add b`), e.g. are they really "unreachable commits", "stale commits"?
    What's the jargon of the act that removes them, e.g. is it "prune", "garbage collection"?
3. People do `git reset` or `git rebase -i` all the time. If they don't somehow remove these stale old commits, will they get a bloating Git repo, especially for LARGE projects with lots of collaborators (like Chromium)?
4. (nice to have) Please explain *why* your answer to 1 works.

footnotes:

[1] I could use `git rebase -i` but I want to do it programmatically instead of interactively so that it can be automated by a script, but that's beside the point)

[2] [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41387676/8385554) does not quite answer my questions

> Update:
>
> This removes all entries showed by `git reflog show`, but I don't quite understand why from
>   reading the docs.. and other questions remain (plz see above)
>
> ```
>     git reflog expire --expire=now --all
> ```
>
> **However**, old commits, though not shown in `git reflog show`, are still `git checkout`-able if you remember the SHA, that means these old commits are not really deleted!!
>
> So this is not the answer.

Comment: Actually your question *is* answered over there, at least in the comments: "Besides reflog entries (which keep objects alive until the reflog entry itself is deleted), all objects get a grace period, 14 days by default [...] `--prune-all`"

Comment: @o11c I tried that, `git gc --prune=all` doesn't delete them.. (added to the list of commands that don't work)

Comment: You don't need to do the add after the soft reset, your index entries all still point the same places (soft reset doesn't touch the index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to expire the reflogs and *then* prune those commits:

```sh
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

As you've figured out, running any one of the above commands doesn't work. You need to run both *in order*.

But usually you shouldn't need to do this manually - git excels at maintaining those records and manually cleaning them up doesn't add much benefits.

Comment: Did you mean `git reflog expire --expire=now --all`?

Comment: @Leedehai Yes it's a typo.

Comment: Thanks! So `git reflog expire` alone really just marks commits as "expired" but doesn't actually remove them?

Comment: Do you pick up every bit of dust the instant it falls?  Let Git's periodic vacuuming clear out any detritus before it builds up too much, it's plenty effective.

Comment: @jthill yeah I know, I know, but let's say I have sensitive information I want to erase