# How to properly use Git and branches

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I'm kind of new to version control with Git.  I read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide) and am following the basic approach that is shown in the diagram *[here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)*.    Still, I have some doubts about how to use Git branches to separate the development of new features from existing code.

Here is an example.  Suppose that at the start, my repository contains the following two main branches:

- Master branch (containing the release version)
- *Develop* branch (containing new fixes or features to separate them from existing project features)

When I need to develop new features or modules, I create branches from *Develop* and start the new code projects there.  For example, I make three new branches to add features related to `Sun`, `Star`, and `SuperNova`.  Now, my repository contains five branches:

- Master branch: Release 1.0.0
- *Develop* branch: Modification after release 1.0.0
- *NewModule_Sun* branch: add Sun to project (create from *Develop* branch)
- *NewModule_Star* branch: add Star to project (create from *Develop* branch)
- *NewModule_SuperNova* branch: add SuperNova to Project (create from *Develop* branch)

For Release 1.0.1, I want to include the the `Sun` and `Star` modules, but not `SuperNova`.  So, I merge them with Develop and then merge Develop with the Release:

1. Merge NewModule_Sun into Develop
2. Merge NewModule_Star into Develop
3. Merge Develop into Master (release 1.0.1)

The *Develop* branch needs to be kept permanently, but the `Sun` and `Star` branches are no longer needed.  They get deleted:

1. Delete the NewModule_Sun branch
2. Delete the NewModule_Star branch

After these changes my repository contains the following three branches:

- Master Branch: Release 1.0.1
- *Develop* Branch: Modification after release 1.0.1
- *NewModule_SuperNova* branch: Modification after release 1.0.0 (created from Develop when it was not merged with the Star/Sun branches)

==

Firstly, am I using Git branches correctly?

Secondly, I reviewed the history of the final *Develop* branch, and it seems that I have lost some information on the `NewModules`.  Is that normal? And, is it possible to transfer all the history information to the *Develop* branch?

Comment: This may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613903/does-deleting-a-branch-in-git-remove-it-from-the-history

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Am I doing a propery use of git?

Yes the workflow that you describe is pretty much standard workflow. You create some branch, you work on it and when you're done you merge it and remove the not needed branch (unless you are going to continue developing on that branch).

> After removing a branch, viewing the history it seems to me that I
>   have lost every information about the branch itself... is that normal?

Yes this is normal.

> is it possible to remove a branch but leaving the history information
>   unbroken?

Not sure what you mean here. As long as you have merged the branch before deleting it, the history is still there. You just merged it into another branch and the history can be seen on that branch. There is no way to know when a branch was deleted if that's what you are asking for.

Comment: ah ok.. I was looking for a way (that you told me that is impossibile) to see the starting and ending of a branch... it's a pity :(

Comment: @Marcx I'm a little late, but maybe you are still looking for this flag "git merge --no-ff branchname"

Answer (score 13):

I suggest you read *[A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)* which defines a good pattern for Git branching.

I have found that I keep development branches for a period, until time renders the change history you made in those revisions not worth keeping (about six months), and then delete them.

Comment: I read that... I'm actually using that system... There is not explained my question about the deletion of a branch... that is basically my main doubt :)

Comment: Thanks.  As a complete n00b to branching paradigms, your link was exactly what I needed.